# Getting started with Sinatra, CouchDB & CouchRest?

Tags: ruby, couchdb, sinatra

I'm just starting to learn my way around CouchDB and Sinatra, but am struggling to find some basic examples of integrating the two via CouchRest. The CouchRest docs assume a little too much to be useful to me yet.

Does anyone have links to useful examples/articles/docs?

Answer (score 1):

Sinatra docs are pretty great and easy to work with.

The examples in the couchrest repo seem to show a lot of use cases. https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model

The best way to understand code (and especially bleeding edge ruby)  is to just read the code.

Updated, with link to tutorial: http://japhr.blogspot.com/2009/03/spike-sinatra-and-couchdb.html

Comment: I have looked at that example, but I was struggling to understand how it would fit into Sinatra. For example, the `SERVER` and `SERVER.default_database` properties... Could they live in a rackup file as they are?

Comment: don't put them in the rackup file.  You should probably have a separate configuration file (analogous to config/environment.rb in rails).  There is nothing special about couch rest or sinatra, it is just normal ruby.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip, Ben :-) Also, after playing around a bit more I've realised that the code in that `example.rb` file is quite dated now. It may be useful for showing a general outline, but it seems the CouchRest API has changed since the example was written (for example, `save` does not work for me but `save_doc` does).

Comment: I wish I could say I was more surprised.  Most of the time when I am working with all but the most commonly used libraries I find myself only reading source code and tests to find out how something works.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into the couch_potato library too, it just hits the sweet spot between the basic approach of couch rest and active record. Source and examples: https://github.com/langalex/couch_potato